# parse date in mm_dd_yyyy format

Tags: c#, parsing, date

I need to parse date in the following format.
mm_dd_yyyy
I know I can do like this

```
var dateString = "20050802";
var date = myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                                    "yyyyMMdd",
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and then replace the -with underscore character. 
But is there any other way around to do the same?

Comment: "Parsing" is conversion from string to date. "Rendering" or "composing" is conversion from date to string. What exactly do you want to achieve? What is the input, and what is the output?

Comment: I just need today's date in mm_dd_yyyy format..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what's the problem?
Just make appropriate format string: `MM_dd_yyyy`.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("08_02_2005", "MM_dd_yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // from string to DateTime
var s = dateTime.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy"); // from DateTime to string
```